# Show google drive files using google drive api for javascript

Tags: javascript, web, google-drive-api

I'm trying view all files and folders uploaded on my google drive. There is written in google drive documentation that you can create your appFolder and can upload/view files of that folder here is its code to list all files within application data folder.

```
function listFilesInApplicationDataFolder(callback) {
  var retrievePageOfFiles = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.items);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageToken': nextPageToken
        });
        retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': '\'appfolder\' in parents'
  });
  retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
}
```

**Question :** can we list all files of all folders of our google drive? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you give mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', it will give list of folders in your drive. To get list of files, in jave you have to give GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q="'<FOLDER_ID>' in parents". It lists the files in the folder id.